# Oracle Apex PL SQL Trigger error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

This is the error I am getting

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
```

This is my code:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON TBLORDERCHARGES

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE W_CHARGETYPE VARCHAR2(1);
        W_CHARGEAMOUNT NUMBER;
        W_DISCOUNTPERCENT NUMBER;

Begin

    SELECT fldPartServiceType
    INTO W_CHARGETYPE
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    SELECT fldPartServiceAmount
    INTO W_CHARGEAMOUNT
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    SELECT fldDiscountPercent
    INTO W_DISCOUNTPERCENT
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    UPDATE TBLORDERCHARGES 
    SET fldChargeType = W_CHARGETYPE,
        fldChargeAmount = W_CHARGEAMOUNT,
        fldDiscountPercent = W_DISCOUNTPERCENT
    WHERE fldChargeId = :new.fldChargeId;

END;
```

I also tried this code, but got the same results:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON TBLORDERCHARGES

FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
W_CHARGETYPE AS VARCHAR(1);
W_CHARGEAMOUNT AS NUMBER;
W_DISCOUNTPERCENT AS NUMBER;
Begin

    W_CHARGETYPE = (SELECT fldPartServiceType FROM tblPartsServices
                    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode);
    W_CHARGEAMOUNT = (SELECT fldPartServiceAmount FROM tblPartsServices
                      WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode);
    W_DISCOUNTPERCENT = (SELECT fldDiscountPercent FROM tblPartsServices
                         WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode);

    UPDATE tblOrderCharges
    SET fldChargeType = W_CHARGETYPE,
        fldChargeAmount = W_CHARGEAMOUNT,
        fldDiscountPercent = W_DISCOUNTPERCENT,
    WHERE fldChargeId = :new.fldChargeId;   
END;
```

and also this code, with no luck whatsoever:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON TBLORDERCHARGES

FOR EACH ROW

Begin


    UPDATE tblOrderCharges AS OC
    SET fldChargeType = (SELECT fldPartServiceType FROM tblPartsServices AS PS 
                         WHERE PS.fldPartServiceId = OC.fldChargeCode),
        fldChargeAmount = (SELECT fldPartServiceAmount FROM tblPartsServices AS PS
                           WHERE PS.fldPartServiceId = OC.fldChargeCode),
        fldDiscountPercent = (SELECT fldDiscountPercent FROM tblPartsServices AS PS
                              WHERE PS.fldPartServiceId = OC.fldChargeCode),
    WHERE fldChargeId = :new.fldChargeId;   

END;
```

Last code I tried, getting very frustrated:

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON TBLORDERCHARGES

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
    W_PARTSERVICE_AMOUNT NUMBER;
    W_PARTSERVICE_DISCOUNT NUMBER;
    W_CHARGE_AMOUNT NUMBER;
    W_PARTSERVICE_ID VARCHAR2(10);
    W_PARTSERVICE_TYPE VARCHAR2(1);
    W_CHARGE_ID NUMBER;
    W_CHARGE_CODE VARCHAR2(10);
    W_CHARGE_TYPE VARCHAR2(1);
    W_CHARGE_REMARKS VARCHAR2(40);
    W_CHARGE_STATUS VARCHAR2(1);
    W_CHARGE_ORDER_ID VARCHAR2(10);
    W_TECHNICIAN_ID VARCHAR2(10);

SELECT fldChargeId, fldChargeCode, fldChargeType, fldRemarks, fldChargeStatus, fldOrderId, fldTechnicianId
INTO W_CHARGE_ID, W_CHARGE_CODE, W_CHARGE_TYPE, W_CHARGE_REMARKS, W_CHARGE_STATUS, W_CHARGE_ORDER_ID, W_TECHNICIAN_ID
FROM tblOrderCharges
WHERE fldChargeId = :new.fldChargeId

SELECT fldPartServiceAmount, fldPartServiceType, fldDiscountPercent
INTO W_PARTSERVICE_AMOUNT, W_PARTSERVICE_TYPE, W_PARTSERVICE_DISCOUNT
FROM tblPartsServices
WHERE fldPartServiceId = W_CHARGE_CODE

Begin

    UPDATE tblOrderCharges
    SET fldChargeAmount = W_PARTSERVICE_AMOUNT,
        fldChargeType = W_PARTSERVICE_TYPE,
        fldDiscountPercent = W_PARTSERVICE_DISCOUNT
    WHERE fldChargeId = W_CHARGE_ID;

END;
```

I don't understand why oracle is not more specific with their code errors. Its getting frustrating. I am stuck here, not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So much errors. first: cut off the DECLARE  word, second: ';' instead of ',' after variables

Comment: and also if y update same row values then use :new.fldChargeType = W_CHARGETYPE instead of update query

Comment: @DmitrySamborskyi With all of your said changes I get an error ```ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification ```

Comment: sorry. use of declare is not an error. my mistake

Answer (score 0):

rewrited

```
create or replace trigger TRG_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON TBLORDERCHARGES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
W_CHARGETYPE VARCHAR2(1);
W_CHARGEAMOUNT NUMBER;
W_DISCOUNTPERCENT NUMBER;

Begin
    SELECT fldPartServiceType
    INTO W_CHARGETYPE
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    SELECT fldPartServiceAmount
    INTO W_CHARGEAMOUNT
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    SELECT fldDiscountPercent
    INTO W_DISCOUNTPERCENT
    FROM TBLPARTSSERVICES
    WHERE fldPartServiceId = :new.fldChargeCode;

    :new.fldChargeType = W_CHARGETYPE;
    :new.fldChargeAmount = W_CHARGEAMOUNT;
    :new.fldDiscountPercent = W_DISCOUNTPERCENT;
END
```

Comment: still getting ```ORA-24344: success with compilation error ``` with your code

Comment: strange. I have success. What api do y use?

Comment: Im doing it directly on oracle apex

Comment: It just says the same error ```ORA-24344: success with compilation error```

Comment: I'm going to try another approach, let you know my results

Comment: TBLPARTSSERVICES, is in apex scheme?

Comment: Yes, tblPartsServices is created, and it has values

Comment: just try to make it directly using sql*plus or some api

Comment: tried the code in sqlfiddle and got this error ```ORA-02091: transaction rolled back ORA-02290: check constraint (SYSTEM.DEFERRED_4_C75E7A_CK) violated```